# how to map hbase to hive?

Tags: hive, hbase

I have an hbase table in the above format:

```
key : userId#country
column family: k
columns: date#visits, visits
```

How to i make an hive table which looks like this:

```
userId, date, country, visits
```

i tried to fiddle my way around with column mapping and so far i only managed to do this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table(key string, visits int)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '#' 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,k:visits")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "kpi");
```

I had been working this for hours, and didn't had much progress. Can some1 point me in the right direction?

---

I found out how to map a hbase key into a hive row, it's not exactly what I want but it helps...:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table(key struct<id:string, country:string>, visits int)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '#' 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,k:visits")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "kpi");
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit more about what the error you're hitting is?

Comment: I am not getting any error, i cannot do it. The code I put is to map the entire key and one of the columns. I keep scouting the Internet to find an working example how to map the column name into a hive column and part of the row key into another column.

Comment: But when you say you can't do it, where does it fail. Does it fail when you input the CREATE statement? Or does the create statement work fine but then you get no results?

Comment: it means my knowledge is not enough. I can only do basic mappings, mappings using the separator could not found any example

Comment: and btw the code i posted works.. however it's only straight mapping, and that's not what what i want. I want to map the content of the separators

Answer (score 0):

Is userId a coulmn in your columnfamily 'k'? if it is then dont give ":key" inside the mapping. Try giving "k:userId"